# Firebase Storage OnSuccessListener is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to uploading image to the Firebase. For that I am using Firebase Storage `OnSuccessListener`. But `OnSuccessListener` is not working. It shows:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'OnSuccessListener'

```
 private void startPosting(){

    mProgess.setMessage("Uploading Quotes");
    mProgess.show();

    final String Quote_val = mPostQuote.getText().toString().trim();

    final String Author_val = mPostAuthor.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Quote_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Author_val) && mImageUri !=  null){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Quote_Image").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatbase.push();
                newPost.child("Quotes").setValue(Quote_val);

                newPost.child("Quote_Author").setValue(Author_val);
                newPost.child("Images").setValue(downloadUrl);
                mProgess.dismiss();

                startActivity(new Intent(adminUpdateQuotesSend.this, QuoteList.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
```

Comment: Add FailureListener also to check if there error.

Comment: update your `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'` version to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'` try with this one

Comment: Please share the content of your both` build.gradle` files. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: You're using an old version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage` (released in 2017). You really should follow [Get Started with Cloud Storage on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) and use the dependency version listed there (currently `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'`).

Comment: I am using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0' @AlexMamo

Comment: i have use that earlier.. but same issue

Comment: I'm asking you again, please share the content of your both` build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CompletionListener:

```
filepath.putFile(mImageUri, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
  void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
     if(error==null){
       //success
     }
  }
});
```